# Recursively list path of files only

Tags: find, diff, recursive, comm

## Why

I have two folders that should contain the exact same files, however, when I look at the number of files, they are different. I would like to know which files/folders are present in one, not the other. My thinking is I will make a list of all the files and then use comm to find differences between the two folders.

## Question

How to make a list recursively of files and folders in the format /path/to/dir and /path/to/dir/file ?

## Important notes

OS:  Windows 11, subsystem Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Locations folders: One network drive, one local

Size of folders: ~2tb each

Comment: Consider using `rsync` in dry run mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any of that, just use `diff -qr dir1 dir2`. For example:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file3
│   ├── file4
│   ├── file6
│   ├── file7
│   ├── file8
│   └── subdir1
│       ├── dsaf
│       ├── sufile1
│       └── sufile3
└── dir2
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    ├── file3
    ├── file4
    ├── file9
    └── subdir1
        ├── sufile1
        └── sufile3

4 directories, 16 files
```

If I now run `diff -qr` (`-r` for "recursive" and `-q` to only report when the files differ, and not show the actual differences) on the two directories, I get:

```
$ diff -qr dir1/ dir2/
Only in dir2/: file2
Only in dir1/: file6
Only in dir1/: file7
Only in dir1/: file8
Only in dir2/: file9
Only in dir1/subdir1: dsaf
```

---

That said, the way to get a list of files is `find`:

```
$ find dir1 -type f
dir1/subdir1/dsaf
dir1/subdir1/sufile1
dir1/subdir1/sufile3
dir1/file6
dir1/file1
dir1/file8
dir1/file4
dir1/file7
dir1/file3
```

Then, you can remove the `dir1/` and `dir2/` using `sed`, and compare the output of two directories using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) in a shell that supports it:

```
$ comm -3 <(find dir1 -type f | sed 's|dir1/||' | sort) <(find dir2 -type f | sed 's|dir2/||' | sort)
    file2
file6
file7
file8
    file9
subdir1/dsaf
```

Note that this assumes file names with no newline characters. If you need to handle those, just use the `diff -r` approach above.

Comment: `diff` would also read and compare all files with the same name, right? That might be unnecessary if it's known that the only differences would be missing files.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, but if the files are identical, it shouldn't be an issue. At worst it will make it run a little slower. But yeah, I added a `-q` so it also won't print the differences.

Comment: That works wonderfully well, thank you! As a side note, I am doing this on Windows 11 subsystem ubuntu. One of the folders (~2tb) is a cloud drive. The find option is a lot faster when accessing a mapped drive. It seems like diff is trying to download the from the cloud, where find doesn't?

Comment: @Olaf, [diff compares (the contents of) files and prints out line-by-line differences](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html). It's pretty much what version control systems use to show differences between versions of source code etc. and even with `-q` it still reads as much as it needs to figure out if the files are identical or not. `find` only looks at the metadata, filenames, dates, such.

Comment: @ilkkachu Understood, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Olaf that isn't a side note, that is the sort of thing you need to put in big bold letters in the question since it could change everything. The `find` approach will indeed be much faster, and 10 times faster if everything is over a network. The fact that you are not runnin
g actual Linux is likely also relevant.

Comment: @terdon thank you for the suggestion, I will edit the original post

Comment: Thanks, @Olaf! Also, don't put it in big bold letters, I was being a bit dramatic :) Just mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that *directories* on Unix are just one of many types of files. With `find`, you can search for them with `-type d`, or use the `/` qualifier in zsh globs. Other types of *files* include *regular files* (`-type f`, `.` glob qualifier, maybe what you meant by *file*), but also symlinks (`-type l` / `@`), devices, fifos, sockets...

To get the files of type *directory*, you can do:

```
find dir1/ -type d
```

And for files of any other type:

```
find dir1/ ! -type d
```

And same for `dir2`.

Now that comes with 3 main problems:

- the printed paths will start with `dir1/` for `dir1` and `dir2/` for `dir2` which would make the comparison more difficult.
- the order will be random.
- the file paths are written one per line, but the newline character is as valid as any in a file path, or in other words, file paths can be made of several lines, so the output is not post-processable reliably.

Those can be addressed with GNU `find` and `sort` by using:

```
find dir1/ -type f -printf '%P\0' | LC_ALL=C sort -z
```

Where:

- `%P` prints the path of the file *relative to dir1*
- we sort the list (in the C locale as file paths don't have to be made of text)
- we use NUL-delimited records instead of lines as 0 is the only byte that cannot occur in a file path.

Now, you can compare the list with:

```
list() {
  find "$@" -printf '%P\0' | LC_ALL=C sort -z
}
echo Directory differences:
comm -z3 <(list dir1/ -type d) <(list dir2/ -type d) | tr '\0' '\n'
echo Non-directory differences:
comm -z3 <(list dir1/ ! -type d) <(list dir2/ ! -type d) | tr '\0' '\n'
```

That output is not post-processable reliably as we translate the NULs back to newline for displays an `comm` uses TABs to separate the columns which again is valid in a file path.

Alternatively, you can get the lists in zsh arrays and use its array comparison operators:

```
dirs_in_dir1=( dir1/**/*(ND/:s:dir1/::) )
dirs_in_dir2=( dir2/**/*(ND/:s:dir2/::) )
nondirs_in_dir1=( dir1/**/*(ND^/:s:dir1/::) )
nondirs_in_dir2=( dir2/**/*(ND^/:s:dir2/::) )
```

Then:

```
dirs_only_in_dir1=( ${dirs_in_dir1:|dirs_in_dir2} )
dirs_only_in_dir2=( ${dirs_in_dir2:|dirs_in_dir1} )
nondirs_only_in_dir1=( ${nondirs_in_dir1:|nondirs_in_dir2} )
nondirs_only_in_dir2=( ${nondirs_in_dir2:|nondirs_in_dir1} )
```

And do what you have to do with those arrays, like `print` them `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn with:

```
print -rC1 -- $array
```

(or `N`UL-delimited so it can be post-processed by adding the `-N` option).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 cd /path/1
 find . -type d -print | sort > list1.dir
 find . -type f -print | sort > list1.file
 cd /path/2
 find . -type d -print | sort > list2.dir
 find . -type f -print | sort > list2.file
```

- `sort` is used to ensure same order, and a smaller result for `diff` or `comm`
- you might use absolute destination file name, so that `list1.file` and `list2.file` will not "polute" results.

Comment: Note that this won't work well if the file names have newlines. Might be worth mentioning.